# Active Record: AND not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this Code in Rails 4:

```
@dominik += Provision.where(teilhaber: 'DW' AND weberkunde: = false).sum(:betrag)*0.9
```

How can I put this right so that the AND (i mean both conditions shall be true (teilhaber: 'DW' and weberkunde: false) functions correctly.

this does not work either:

```
@dominik += Provision.where(teilhaber: 'DW').where(weberkunde: = false).sum(:betrag)*0.9 #and weberkunde: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using a hash

```
.where(teilhaber: 'DW', weberkunde: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails has an excellent guide for querying active record:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

In your case, the syntax for your where query is just a bit off.  You have a few different options with the where method.

To use hash conditions:

`Provision.where(teilhaber: 'DM', weberkund: false)`

Or, you can also use a a SQL-esque syntax.

`Provision.where("teilhaber = ? AND weberkund = ?", 'DM', 'false')`